# Does full Push Down Optimization allow Database Server to load data to target tables without intervention of Informatica Server?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to learn more about pushdown optimization (PDO) in Informatica.
As per my research you can have below 3 kinds of PDO at Informatica:

- Source side PDO
- Target side PDO
- Full PDO

I am curious to know if full PDO can push entire Informatica code to either Source DB or Target DB or some portion to source DB and remaining to target DB? It would be good from performance perspective if entire code is pushed to target DB then returned results should be loaded to target tables by target DB server itself. 
Need your help to understand how it works exactly. If PDO at target is enabled then results will be returned to Informatica Power Center (IPC) server and then it’s responsibility of IPC to process the results returned by target DB to target table or it is directly processed by target db server to target tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO is a giant SQL clause of Informaticatransformations. Informatica creates a big SELECT statement or INSERT/UPDATE statement based on whatever it can/can not do and issue it in DB rather than processing it in server.
When you run a session configured for

- Source side PDO - the Integration Service analyzes the mapping from the source to the target or until it reaches a downstream transformation it cannot push to the source database. creates big SELECT statement.
- Target side PDO - the Integration Service analyzes the mapping from the target back to the source or until it reaches a upstream transformation it cannot push to the target database. creates big INSERT/UPDATE statement.
- Full PDO - the Integration Service analyzes the mapping from the source to the target or until it reaches a downstream transformation it cannot push to the target database. Works when source and target are on same db.

There is no single best practice. All depends on your mapping. If  you have simple transformations then target PDO is good. If you have multiple active transformations or union, joiner,lookup to another DB, PDO should be decided on their distance from source/target.

You can go through this for more info - https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/advanced-workflow-guide/pushdown-optimization.html

Comment: Thank you Koushik , nicely explained and helpful URL. One thing which I am still curious to know- In case of target PDO weather results of query execution  are firstly returned to integration service and then integration service populates results to target table(@target DB) or  target DB server can directly load the returned/resulted records of query execution to target tables ?

Comment: It depends on possibility for IC to create single SQL. If it can create single SQL, then it will be issued directly in DB. Else, it will extract data into IC server before applying to target. For example, if there is a simple mapping like Source -> SQ -> EXP->FIL->Target. IC will directly create INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...FROM SOURCE statement and issue into target DB.